# what's the difference between these two residual plots?

Tags: r, regression, residuals, linear

I have a table of x,y data points in a text document called "data.txt"

```
data <- read.table("data.txt", header = T)
x <- data$x
y <- data$y
fit <- lm(y~x, data)

res = residuals(fit)       # method 1
plot(y, e)

plot(resid(fit))           # method 2
```

I'm not sure why, but why do these methods produce different plots?
Shouldn't both of these methods plot residuals on y values?

Comment: One plots the residuals against the index, the other plots the residuals against the actual values.  Same data, different view.

Comment: Thank you @DemetriPananos